# Jmeter Websocket socket.io request not received in Nestjs

Tags: socket.io, jmeter, nestjs

I have a Nestjs server i am able to send connection request using the below code

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000", {
    transports: ["websocket"],
    pingTimeout: 10000,
    pingInterval: 25000,
});
const someDelay = 10;
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected...');
})
```

The request is received successfully. The issue is when sending the same request using JMETER it never reaches the server

[image]

after opening the connection i am sending a request with token and it never reaches server

[image]
It doesn't give any error but never reaches server

Following is the error on request-response-sampler

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you're only opening a connection, you're not sending any "request", consider adding either a **single-write sampler** or **request-response sampler** and you should see the request "reaching" the server.

See [Basic request-response sample.jmx](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/Basic%20request-response%20sample.jmx) example test plan and [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) for more information.

Comment: I have updated my question. i am sending a request after opening a connection. it still never reaches server. i am using socket.io 4.4.0 on server